# Unable to copy text from UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have to delete an entry from a UILabel. I am doing so by copying its text to a string variable and deleting the end index to the string. The UILabel does contain a value but the string it is being copied to contains nothing. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
var displayString = display.text!
displayString.removeAtIndex(displayString.endIndex) //error at this line.
display.text! = displayString
```

The state of the string can be seen in this screenshot.
[image]

and the debugger can be seen here that the display UILabel actually does contain the string.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not remove the `endIndex`, but the one before the end. **And** you should only remove something from the string if there actually is something to remove - check for the empty string before removing a character:

```
if displayString != "" {
    displayString.removeAtIndex(displayString.endIndex.predecessor())
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. I tried accepting the answer but it wouldn't let me. Says it has to be done within 5 minutes of answering. Apologies for that.

Comment: Done that. Gosh, Stackoverflow is playing with my mind today. And you earned a second set of thanks from me. Thanks a lot man.